# How to find GPS source (Location provider) and Heading in Nmea String

Tags: java, nmea

I want to find GPS source and Heading in a Nmea string , I have found latitude , longitude , accuracy , speed and time in the string but I can't find GPS source and Heading . I need help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different NMEA sentences contain different morsels of information. For example, the $GPGGA contains "Global Positioning System Fix Data" and the $GPRMC contains "Recommended minimum specific GPS/Transit data"

If you've already found lat, long, accuracy, speed, and time (remember, time and date are in UTC), I'm guessing you're looking at $GPRMC sentences, which are the most basic of the NMEA sentences.

For GPS Heading, it's simply the 8th field in the $GPRMC - the "Course Made Good" or "True Course", and it's measured in degrees clockwise from N. That information is also in the $GPHDT (Heading True) or $GPVTG (Track Made Good) sentences if you have those.

I don't know what you mean by "GPS Source." If you want information about the satellites that gave your receiver the fix, look at the $GPGSA (basic information) or $GPGSV (more detailed info).

You can read more about NMEA sentences at http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/